# Add app shortcut to homescreen in Lenovo A7000

Tags: launcher, home-screen-shortcuts, lenovo

I have Lenovo A7000 with Android 5.0

I've accidentally removed Chrome shortcut from my homescreen. How can I put it back? I don't mean shortcut to a certain webpage, I really mean just shortcut for running Chrome itself on my phone. Now when I want to run Chrome I have to go all the way into the Settings-->Apps-->Chrome and click on Launch - that takes forever.

I need icon on homescreen back but there doesnt seem to be an obvious way of how to do it. When I hold on an empty space i get an option to "add or edit widget" and I can choose from dozens of predefined shortcuts and add them to homescreen. However there is NO chrome shortcut here, only bunch of other google services and other apps installed on my phone.

Help pls!

Comment: What launcher is it?

Comment: I dont understand the question. What do you mean by "launcher" in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your app drawer, long tap on Crome icon then you'll be able to place it on home screen.

Comment: If you mean this: http://www.beginandroid.com/appdrawer.shtml I dont have such a thing on my screen anywhere :(

Comment: Alright I installed App Drawer as an app - when i try to use to put Chrome icon on desktop by "create shortcut" it says "Shortcut Chrome already exists" (but it doesnt omg).

Comment: Aaaaand it works after restarting the phone - thanks man!